# How does an unemployed EU national get an EHIC in Spain?

Tags: spain, ehic

I am an [EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union) national residing in Spain, I have a [certificate of residency registration](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%B3n_municipal_de_habitantes) and my [foreigner identity number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIE_number) but I do not work and have not worked for the last five years. I arrived to Spain in early 2018, with an EHIC issued by the UK where resided and worked part-time for over one year before my move to Spain. This EHIC from the UK expired at the beginning of 2022. I was asked for my EHIC only once when applying for my foreigner identity number here in 2018. Since than I've been supporting myself out of my savings, banks transfers of my mother and occasional small jobs at [grey market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_economy). Is there a way of obtaining a [European Health Insurance Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Health_Insurance_Card)  that does not involve being employed? What documents would I need for that?

Comment: The European Health Insurance Card (EHIC) is issued by your **statutory** (as apposed to a *private*) health insurance provider. So what type of health provider do you have?

Comment: Does https://www.seg-social.es/wps/portal/wss/internet/Trabajadores/PrestacionesPensionesTrabajadores/10938/11566/1761#128805 help?

Comment: @Traveller The link does not help much. It does not tell me whether an institution like the unemployment office or the city where I reside would help me with getting such a card. The link also does not mention other than online methods of asking for the card.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I don't know it. I want to be provided with public healthcare of Spain (funded from taxes and tax-like contributions).  How might I go about this?

Comment: You must of had some form of insurance when you arrived in Spain. Freedom of Movement Article 7 (Right of residence for more than three months) (1)(b) *... and have **comprehensive sickness insurance cover in the host Member State**;*

Comment: Further information is required for this question. How did you support yourself after arrival in Spain? Did you ever work in Spain? How do you support yourself now? etc.

Comment: @MarkJohnson GIven what we know here about the varieties of immigration formalities, I think it's quite possible that the OP arrived in Spain (or elsewhere in Schengen) and was not asked about health coverage.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Yes, that is true but does not change the fact that it is still a requirement. In Germany, by default, no checks are done. But should it later come to their attention that these conditions have not been fulfilled they can react. Turning up later stating 'I have no medical coverage, give me one for free' would be such a situation.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, I agree. I don't mean to suggest that the OP gets a pass on the insurance requirement.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I supplied additional information in my question in response to your worthy comment.

Comment: I don't think we can give much help here. Basically your 'papers' are not in order (no health insurance since 2023). You need assistance to get them back into order. Often there will be social organisations that assist people in gettings these type of things resolved. They will know the in's and out's of the 'system' and will often activly assist you in getting it done. Finding (a reliable) one locally will be the hardest part. (I assume you are not a UK citizen)

Comment: "I want to be provided with public healthcare of Spain (funded from taxes and tax-like contributions)": from the (fairly cursory) research I've done it appears that Spain makes this system available to the people who have paid into it through taxes and tax-like contributions (with the majority of contributions for employees coming from the employer). For self-sufficient foreigners such as yourself, private insurance seems to be the solution.  Perhaps if you start reporting your gray market income, thereby becoming legitimately self-employed, you will be able to join the system.

Comment: It should be noted that a **private insurance** is **not** a **statutory insurance** and therefore not a EHIC card (which is printed on the back side of the health card and is blank for cards issued by a private insurances).

Comment: I feel the private vs. statutory distinction is a bit of a red herring and all the comments are very unhelpful in addressing the OP's confusion. The EHIC is design to cover short to medium stays in other European countries. There are some corner cases but it is not intended to provide healthcare when you reside permanently in another EU country (which appears to be your case). What you need to figure out is how to access the local healthcare system.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The Freedom of movement directive does not create an insurance obligation, let's try to avoid confusing things further.